# Creating hash with multiple words using split method

Tags: ruby

So I have a text file and some of the values are :
mom : dad
brother : sister

I created a hash with using this file:

```
hash = Hash[*File.read('file.txt').delete(":").split(/[, \n]+/)]
```

It works fine with one worded values such as brother: sister but if add, metallica : rock band it does not work. So I have 2 questions:

1- I didn't really understand .split(/[, \n]+/)] method there. Why did we add too many symbols inside? (Such as +,/) What they did?
2 - How can I create metallica => rock band ? Or green day => band. Is it possible to do with this split method?

Comment: maybe `scan` would be the better tool here?

Comment: Is that the actual content because the syntax is fairly close to YAML in which case parsing would be more efficient and less error prone than string manipulation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's create a file for illustration.

```
f = 't'

File.write(f, <<~END
mom : dad
brother : sister
no colon in this line
metallica : rock band
  green day : band
END
)
  #=> 90
```

Have a look.

```
puts File.read(f)
mom : dad
brother : sister
no colon in this line
metallica : rock band
  green day : band
```

We can read the file line-by-line and build the hash as we go.

```
IO.foreach(f).with_object({}) do |line, h|
  next unless line.count(':') == 1
  key, value = line.split(':').map(&:strip)
  h[key] = value
end
  #=> {"mom"=>"dad", "brother"=>"sister",
  #    "metallica"=>"rock band", "green day"=>"band"}
```

Note that without a block, [IO::foreach](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) returns an enumerator, which I've chained to [Enumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object).

Comment: _Why did we add to many symbols inside? (Such as +,/) What they did?_ ;)

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that `.split(/[, \n]+/)` will split by comma, empty space and new line, that mean phrase ("green day") will split into multiple key-value pairs.

Alternative approach would be to split key-value pairs by lines and split key and value by `:` character

```
hash =  File.readlines('file.txt').map {|line| line.split(':').map(&:strip)}.to_h
```

Comment: normally split(//) splits words letter by letter, but in there we put [, \n] . I do understand that part as well. But why did we use + after ] ? What it produced?

Comment: `+` to accept multiple characters, for split `"a,,,b.     c".split(/[, \n]+/)` returns `[a,b,c]`, without `+` every comma or empty space will produce an empty item in the final array